# Kubuntu won't start X

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, xorg, kde, gui

My Kubuntu 18.04 LTS installation has been failing to load any kind of GUI on boot, but I still have my MythTV backend and OpenHAB 2 server working just fine on the same machine, as well as SSH access and a perfectly usable tty2 after I ctrl+alt+F2. After the first time I did software updates since the problem started, I also got a mouse cursor that I can move around the black screen on ctrl+alt+F1, but nothing I can do with it.

When I previously thought I was having driver issues, I found the `ubuntu-drivers` command and I saw this at the top of the output before having to ctrl+c it before it flooded the screen:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers debug
=== log messages from detection ===
DEBUG:root:Driver package virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe is incompatible with current X.org server ABI xorg-video-abi-23
```

([here's the full output, from running that over SSH](https://pastebin.com/pg3tZ1c4))

Is this the source of my problem, and how do I fix it? I've tried removing and reinstalling kubuntu-desktop and a handful of its dependencies.

More information is available on request. I really want to avoid nuking the whole thing and reinstalling.

Edit: I noticed today when trying `startx` that it was telling me the log file was at /var/log/Xorg.1.log, so I tried specifying :0

```
$ sudo startx -- :0                                              
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Resource temporarily unavailable
xinit: server error
```

Is this a useful error that gets me somewhere on the path to diagnosing the problem?